# EditText inside a ScrollView display keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, scrollview

I have this layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >



<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

..and when i execute my app, keyboard is displayed.

http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/2879/screenshot2013041012264.png

If i don't use scroll view, this don't happen unless i click one edittext.

I want not to display keyboard (having scrollview) when i execute my app unless i click edittext.

any idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put  ***android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"*** in Activity tag of Manifest file